# SimpleModal - Can still scroll behind modal after setting modal: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

So I am using SimpleModal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

and I can't seem to get it to block scrolling behind the modal.

**modal [Boolean:true]** 
User will be unable to interact with the page below the modal or tab away from the dialog. If false, the overlay, iframe, and certain events will be disabled allowing the user to interact with the page below the dialog.

```
function getStatus(baseURL, programID, appID){
var src = baseURL + "/admin/statepost/" + programID + "/" + appID ;
$.modal('<iframe id="statusIframe" src="' + src + '" height="1000" width="800" style="border:10px">', {
    escClose: false,
    modal: true,
    overlayClose: false,
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#000",
        borderColor:"#fff",
        padding:0
    }
});
```

}

you will see I have modal: true but I still can scroll behind the modal. is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this plugin but I would guess it has something to do with the iframe in your modal.

That said, you can use the `onOpen()` and `onClose()` callbacks to achieve this.

```
  onShow: function(dialog) {
    $("body").addClass("no-scroll");
  },
   onClose: function(dialog) {
    $("body").removeClass("no-scroll");
    $.modal.close(); //Must call this for the plugin to work
  },
```

The CSS for your `<body>` element is straightforward:

```
.no-scroll {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

I put an example up on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sco_tt/dmxrqgz9/4/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to inhibit the body scrolling you can add on modal show the style:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

and on modal close you need to remove that:

```
$('body').css('overflow', '');
```

The snippet (from a demo):

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#confirm-dialog input.confirm, #confirm-dialog a.confirm').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // example of calling the confirm function
        // you must use a callback function to perform the "yes" action
        confirm("Continue to the SimpleModal Project page?", function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://simplemodal.com';
        });
    });
});

function confirm(message, callback) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        escClose: false,
        modal: true,
        overlayClose: false,
        containerCss:{
            backgroundColor:"#000",
            borderColor:"#fff",
            padding:0
        },
        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
        position: ["20%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container',
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            $('body').css('overflow', '');
            this.close();
        },
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            var modal = this;

            $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

            // if the user clicks "yes"
            $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                // call the callback
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    //callback.apply();
                }
                $('body').css('overflow', '');
                // close the dialog
                modal.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#confirm {display:none;}

/* Overlay */
#confirm-overlay {background-color:#eee;}

/* Container */
#confirm-container {height:140px; width:420px; font: 16px/22px 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; text-align:left; background:#fff; border:2px solid #336699;}
#confirm-container .header {height:30px; line-height:30px; width:100%; background:url(../img/confirm/header.gif) repeat-x; color:#fff; font-weight:bold;}
#confirm-container .header span {padding-left:8px;}
#confirm-container .message {color:#333; font-size:14px; margin:0; padding:12px 4px 12px 8px;}
#confirm-container .buttons {line-height:26px; width:160px; float:right; padding:10px 8px 0;}
#confirm-container .buttons div {float:right; margin-left:4px; width:70px; height:26px; color:#666; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; background:url(../img/confirm/button.gif) repeat-x; border:1px solid #bbb; cursor:pointer;}
#confirm-container a.modal-close,
#confirm-container a.modal-close:link,
#confirm-container a.modal-close:active,
#confirm-container a.modal-close:visited {text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; position:absolute; right:10px; top:2px; color:#fff;}
#confirm-container a.modal-close:hover {color:#ccc;}
body {background:#fff; color:#333; font: 12px/22px verdana, arial, sans-serif; height:800px; margin:0 auto; width:100%;}
h1 {color:#3a6d8c; font-size:34px; line-height:40px; margin:0;}
h3 {color:#3a6d8c; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; font-weight:normal; margin:0 0 8px 0;}
img {border:0;}
#logo {margin-bottom:20px; width:300px;}
#logo h1 {color:#666; letter-spacing:-1px; font-weight:normal;}
#logo h1 span {color:#444; font-weight:bold;}
#logo .title {color:#999; font-size:12px;}
#container {margin:0 auto; padding-top:20px; width:800px;}
#content {border-bottom:1px dotted #999; border-top:1px dotted #999; padding:20px 0;}
#footer {clear:left; color:#888; margin:20px 0;}
#footer a:link, #footer a:visited {color:#888; text-decoration:none;}
#footer a:hover {color:#333; text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ericmmartin/simplemodal/master/src/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>


<div id='container'>
    <div id='logo'>
        <h1>Simple<span>Modal</span></h1>
        <span class='title'>A Modal Dialog Framework Plugin for jQuery</span>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='confirm-dialog'>
            <h3>Confirm Override</h3>
            <p>A modal dialog override of the JavaScript confirm function. Demonstrates the use of the <code>onShow</code> callback as well as how to display a modal dialog confirmation instead of the default JavaScript confirm dialog.</p>
            <input type='button' name='confirm' class='confirm' value='Demo'/> or <a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo</a>
        </div>

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id='confirm'>
            <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
            <div class='message'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='' alt='' />
            <img src='' alt='' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
        &copy; 2013 <a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/'>Eric Martin</a><br/>
        <a href='https://github.com/ericmmartin/simplemodal'>SimpleModal on GitHub</a><br/>
        <a href='http://twitter.com/ericmmartin'>@ericmmartin</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/simplemodal'>@simplemodal</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  For anyone reading this. This response is same answer as accepted one but with extra info. Great for further reference.